# What's the default expiration time for block caches?

Tags: 7, caching

This [article](http://blog.merge.nl/20120118/how-does-caching-work-drupal) explains the cache setting in Drupal 7.

I'm using [Blockcache_alter](http://drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter) to cache some blocks. It's not clear to me how long those blocks are cached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing special here. It's the same as on your `admin/config/development/performance` page. Module *Block Cache Alter* just alters `'cache'` key for block and does not interfere with the mechanism of caching in Drupal.

```
Example 1:
Minimum cache lifetime: none,
Cron: every day,
Block cache will be flushed every day or if someone flush cache manually.  
On node or comment submit: the whole block cache will be flushed.
```

In Example 1 the whole block and page cache will be flushed **immediately** on every new comment, node, vote submit because of `Minimum cache lifetime: none`. See where [cache_clear_all() is called](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/calls/cache_clear_all/7).

```
Example 2:
Minimum cache lifetime: 12 hours,
Cron: every 6 hours,
Block cache will be flushed every 12 hours or if someone flush cache manually. 
On node or comment submit: only block cache older than 12 hours will be flushed.
```

Block and page cache items which are **older than 12 hours** will be flushed immediately on every new comment, node, vote submit. See where [cache_clear_all() is called](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/calls/cache_clear_all/7).

Cron period is important because Drupal tries to flush caches on every cron run.

This behaviour can be changed with [Cache Expiration](https://drupal.org/project/expire) module.